# SQl query to get Daily count and amount based on type

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

Consider a table "Customer", and below are the columns

```
CreationDatetime
CustType
Amount
```

In column CustType there can be only 2 values either 1 0r 2.

Now, i want to write oracle sql query in which i will get the daily count of users and the amount added for the day based on unique customer type,

| CreationDate | Total Count of CustType 1 | Total Amount of CustType 1 | Total Count of CustType 2 | Total Amount of CustType 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 100 | 200,000 | 80 | 100,000 |
| 2/1/2021 | 20 | 40,000 | 10 | 10,000 |

I'm using below query but it provide total daily count not based on cust type. Please advise.

```
SELECT Trunc(CreationDatetime),Count(1),SUM(amount)
FROM Customer
group by Trunc(CreationDatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT      TRUNC(CreationDatetime) AS Date, CustType AS CustomerType, COUNT(*) AS DailyCount, SUM(Amount) AS AmountForTheDay
FROM        Customer
GROUP BY    TRUNC(CreationDatetime), CustType
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `sum` + `case` combination:

```
select trunc(creationdatetime) datum,
  sum(case when custtype = 1 then 1      else 0 end) count_of_type_1,
  sum(case when custtype = 1 then amount else 0 end) amount_of_type_1,
  --
  sum(case when custtype = 2 then 1      else 0 end) count_of_type_2,
  sum(case when custtype = 2 then amount else 0 end) amount_of_type_2
from customer
group by trunc(creationdatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get your desired output:

```
SELECT 
   Trunc(CreationDatetime),
   SUM(CASE WHEN CustType=1 THEN 1 END) as "Total Count of CustType 1",
   SUM(CASE WHEN CustTYpe=1 THEN amount END) as "Total Amount of CustType 1",
   SUM(CASE WHEN CustType=2 THEN 1 END) as "Total Count of CustType 2",
   SUM(CASE WHEN CustTYpe=2 THEN amount END) as "Total Amount of CustType 2"
FROM Customer
group by Trunc(CreationDatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`pivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) for this:

> ```
> select
>   trunc(creationdatetime) as dt
>   , CUST_TYPE1_TOTAL_COUNT
>   , CUST_TYPE1_TOTAL_AMOUNT
>   , CUST_TYPE2_TOTAL_COUNT
>   , CUST_TYPE2_TOTAL_AMOUNT
> from t
> pivot (
>   count(*) as total_count
>   , sum(amount) as total_amount
>   
>   for custtype in (
>     1 as cust_type1
>     , 2 as cust_type2
>   )
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> DT        | CUST_TYPE1_TOTAL_COUNT | CUST_TYPE1_TOTAL_AMOUNT | CUST_TYPE2_TOTAL_COUNT | CUST_TYPE2_TOTAL_AMOUNT
> :-------- | ---------------------: | ----------------------: | ---------------------: | ----------------------:
> 19-JUL-21 |                      1 |                      70 |                      0 |                    null
> 17-JUL-21 |                      2 |                     400 |                      1 |                     200
> 18-JUL-21 |                      2 |                     110 |                      2 |                      70
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1b665f3de2bad5420bf129c1df87950)*